# Loop over createElement in java script not executing completely

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, createelement

I am writing code for my e-commerce prototype website. I need to create a dynamic drop-down in one of pages in which it will receive drop-down values (like color here) from database and then I have to create drop-down using that.
I have written following code so far for this.

```
//Json object retrieved from database
var tmp = {"category_id":4,"product_available_quantity":20,"product_color":["Red","Blue","Yellow"],"product_condition":"new","product_description":"Branded Metal Body 4 Star","product_discount":0,"product_id":1,"product_img_url":"http://localhost:5224/ebaytester/images/s-l1600.jpg","product_name":"Motorola Cover","product_price":250,"product_shipping":"free","product_sold_quantity":10,"sub_category_id":7};

//dropdown code for color
    var col_div = document.createElement('div');
    col_div.className = "dropdown";
    var col_btn = document.createElement('button');
    var col_span = document.createElement("span");
    col_span.className = "caret";
    col_btn.className = "btn dropdown-toggle";
    col_btn.setAttribute("type","button");
    col_btn.setAttribute("data-toggle","dropdown");
    text_node = document.createTextNode("Select");
    col_btn.appendChild(text_node);
    col_btn.appendChild(col_span);
    col_div.appendChild(col_btn);
    var ulst = document.createElement('UL');
    ulst.className = "dropdown-menu";
    var color = tmp['product_color'];
    document.write(tmp['product_color'].length);
    for(var i=0;i<tmp['product_color'].length;i++) 
        {

        var list = createElement('li');
        var anc = createElement('a');
        text_node = createTextNode(tmp['product_color'][i]);
        anc.setAttribute('href','#');
        anc.appendChild(text_node);
        list.appendChild(anc);
        ulst.appendChild(list);
        document.write(tmp['product_color'][i]);
        }
    col_div.appendChild(ulst);


    document.getElementById("second").appendChild(col_div);
```

After tracking I finds out the problem is in for loop. As soon as it executes first createElement method it came out from loop abruptly. I have cross check all the syntax several times but all seems fine. I am using DOM(Document Object Model) first time so excuse me for mistakes and please tell me if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Please create a working snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by snippet. If part of the code you want to know which is not working then that is the "for" loop. Loop is not executing properly.

Comment: And apologies for not mentioning that the last statement(getElementById("second")) is one of the division tag in my page where I have to create the dropdown. Thanks

Comment: createElement('li') you are calling a method which is not defined

Comment: I think it does not matters(case sensitiveness in createElement method). I have tried several times with div, button it always works. Although here even I change "li" to "LI" still error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As soon as it executes first createElement method it came out from
>   loop abruptly.

Unless you have your own custom `createElement` method, your browser is likely to throw an error (check your dev-console) indicating that  `createElement` method is `undefined`.

Replace it with `document.createElement`

or create your own `createElement` method as

```
function createElement( name )
{
    return document.createElement( name );
}
```

Comment: Thanks So Much . I got it but still my drop down is not appearing can you tell about that too ?

Comment: I can't unless you share a working snippet (using `<>` in the toolbar) and tell us what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

your could be like this . if you want. problem with your create element method. this approach you can follow with appending with your class name etc.

```
 var tmp = { "category_id": 4, "product_available_quantity": 20, "product_color": ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"], "product_condition": "new", "product_description": "Branded Metal Body 4 Star", "product_discount": 0, "product_id": 1, "product_img_url": "http://localhost:5224/ebaytester/images/s-l1600.jpg", "product_name": "Motorola Cover", "product_price": 250, "product_shipping": "free", "product_sold_quantity": 10, "sub_category_id": 7 };
   window.onload = function () {
       //dropdown code for color
       var div = document.querySelector("#container"),
        frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
         select = document.createElement("select");
       var options = tmp.product_color;
       select.options.add(new Option("--Select--", "-1", true, true));
       for (var i = 1; i < options.length;i++)
           select.options.add(new Option(options[i], options[i]));
       frag.appendChild(select);
       div.appendChild(frag);
   }

<div id="container">

</div>
```